# Alternative to JQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been looking at this article: https://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/

Which suggests using jQuery.load('url #container') to ajax load in a specific div within another page. But the comments are full of "yeah but this is awful for bandwidth, to load a whole page and parse out just one part". But nobody ever offers an alternative solution.

Can anyone offer a comprehensive alternative?

Comment: How concerned about bandwidth are you? A good starting point would be reducing the content in the called files if you never anticipate using the entire file anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends at what level you're talking. `jQuery.load` was really useful for tab controls and the like when there was no better alternative. Now, there are a lot of techniques people use in order to achieve this.

The most common use cases of `jQuery.load` were for entire pages (e.g. to "fake" a MV* type functionality) or for sections of a page (e.g. newsfeed that you update with new content)

**Entire pages**

For entire pages loaded (e.g. a tab control) you tend to see routing libraries used, e.g. [angular routing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) or perhaps a more lightweight example, [Crossroads.js](http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/).

The way these work is by modifying the [location hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/hash) which does not force a page refresh and then loads content from the specified template (.html) file.

The reason why this is better is that `jQuery.load` for pages results in an ever expanding DOM, whereas routes "clean" up after themselves by removing elements from the DOM that would no longer be "visible" on that page.

**Templates within pages**

The second most common use case for `jQuery.load` was to load content into a section of a page. The most common thing seen done here today is to use a templating library, for example, [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

The way these work are to define your markup in a script tag. You then load your content (usually JSON) from a web server or whatever and then apply the template to that JSON and append the resulting markup to the container.

The reason why this is more efficient than `jQuery.load` for an entire page is because you load back just the raw data needed and apply it to a known template rather than load the entire result from a page.